# root law for limits

Tags: limits

I have seen two different statements for root law for limits in Calculus books. This is the first one I found.

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \sqrt[n]{f(x)}  = \sqrt[n]{ \lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)} = \sqrt[n]{L}$$

for all $L$ if $n$ is odd and for $L \geq 0$ if $n$ is even. Second definition I found is as

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \sqrt[n]{f(x)}  = \sqrt[n]{ \lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)} = \sqrt[n]{L}$$

If $n$ is even, we assume that $L > 0$.

So, which one is more accurate definition here ?

Thanks

Comment: I highly doubt this law applies in complex analysis

Comment: @FShrike, so, which one is accurate statement here ?

Comment: To my eyes, they seem identical *when considering real numbers only*.

Comment: They are both correct with some assumptions on $f$.

Comment: @a1402 I'm curious - which assumptions on $f$? I thought that a limit may be passed inside a function so long as that function is continuous, and $x^{1/n}$ is a continuous function, right?

Comment: @FShrike Yes, I think continuity in a neighborhood of $a$ and the existence of the limit should be enough.

Comment: @user9026: My answer contained an error that I have now corrected. We don't need to require that $f$ be continuous at $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct statement is: if $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)$ exists in $\Bbb{R}$, then
$$
\lim_{x \to a}\sqrt[n]{f(x)}=\sqrt[n]{\lim_{x\to a}f(x)}
$$
for all odd $n$. If $n$ is even, then we have to require that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ is greater than $0$. If it is equal to $0$, then again the limit law might fail. For example,
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\sqrt{-x^2}
$$
does not exist because the definition of "$f(x)\to l$ as $x\to a$" requires that $f$ is defined in a neighbourhood of $a$, and $\sqrt{-x^2}$ is not defined in a neighbourhood of $0$. (Sometimes, the definition of a limit is loosened so that $a$ need only be an accumulation point of the domain of $f$, but I believe that this definition of the limit is typically not adopted in elementary calculus.)

Comment: Why do we require that f(a) is bigger than 0 for even?

Comment: @user57928: What I wrote was incorrect, and I have edited my post. Is there anything that remains unclear to you? I am happy to address it.